# Instance isn't passsing given variables to class

Tags: java, class, object, bukkit, instance-variables

first of all; Thanks for reading and helping me out, I'm new to Java I ran into a problem.

I've made instance variables inside a particular class. After this I create a new instance/object of this class and specify the new input of the variable. The problem is: when I run the code and try if its working, it isnt working. It appears that the new variable is not passed to the class being instantiated.
(When I left click the emerald block an empty string appears)

What I've already tried:

- creating a setter method to set the variable.
- using a constructor

Class that I want to make an instance of:

```
package rico.polkadot;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;

public class InstanceClass implements Listener {
    
    public String name;     
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        
        Action action = e.getAction();
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        Block b = e.getClickedBlock();
        
        if(action.equals(Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
            if(b.getType().equals(Material.EMERALD_BLOCK)) {
                p.sendMessage(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
package rico.polkadot;

import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new InstanceClass(this),this);
        InstanceClass test = new InstanceClass();{
            test.name = "lol";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "that I want to make an instance of", you are making an instance of it, one called test.

Comment: It doesn't seem that there is a problem with setting the variable. You have a public variable, and you are setting it after you created the instance called _test_

Comment: @Stultuske oh, well excuse me. Im making an instance with the name test but with the string variable name changed to "lol". Still, it doesnt work when I run the code.. (No message with the string "lol" pops up when I break the emerald block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should make a constructor or at least setter in your `InstanceClass` - best option:

```
public class InstanceClass implements Listener {

    public String name;

    public InstanceClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then you are asking about instance. You created one inside your `onEnable()` function, but you have to remember, it is not accessible outside of this function, so you can't just access this `test` variable from your `InstanceClass`.

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    // here you create instance of InstanceClass
    InstanceClass test = new InstanceClass("lol");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help AP11, I've tried it but it didnt work.. I also have to register the listener in nnEnable (didnt included it in my post) Code needed to register events:  
               getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new InstanceClass(null),this);

Answer (score 0):

Solved, needed multiple constructors and "RegisterEvents" in the onEnable. Thanks for helping.